# To Generate source code from Enterprise architect according to ObjectID

Tags: c++, uml, enterprise-architect

I have imported the source code(C++) into Enterprise Architect 12 for class diagram, Now I'm again generating the source code from the EA.
Code is successfully generated but the problem is

> The Code is not in sequence according to Object ID, so Whenever I run that code in VS2013 it will throw the error.

In order to overcome this error I have to arrange the code according to previous source code which is imported into EA.

Could you please suggest me how to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to turn off alphabetic sorting for features?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @GeertBellekens I tried that feature by turning it off. It works for attributes and methods inside the class.  but it doesn't solve the problem for classes. Still I can see all the class is in alphabetical order. 
Again I have to solve this problem by manually.
the main problem : Generated code is around 18K lines. so it's very difficult to solve.